# Error 500 while using bearer token with Spring boot + Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, token, keycloak, http-status-code-500

This is my first Keycloack integration with a SpringBoot + Spring Security app, and i found myself in a problem. I am using the Keycloak Spring Security Adapter, but something is missing since an error 500 is shown instead of authorizing the request by bearer_token. When i don't send the token, an authorization problem presents which makes sense (401 Unauthorized), but when i do insert a token an error 500 is presented. This happens however with endpoint that specify @RolesAllowed(), since those that doesn't have it can be fetch just fine.

Something you might notice is that for this kind of services is that usually the Access Type would be *bearer-only*, but for this instance is *public*. For this project is necessary unless there's no other choice to this and *bearer-only* is the only way.

**General information**

```
Keycloak:
- Running at port 3000
- Version 18.0.0
Springboot:
- Running at port 8080
- Version 2.7.1

Realm:
- Name:
  * TRP (all uppercase)

Client:
- Client ID: <clientName>
- Access type: Public
- Standard Flow Enabled and Direct Access Grants Enabled enabled
- Valid Redirect URIs: http://localhost:8080/*
- Base URL: http://localhost:3000/
- Admin URL: http://localhost:3000/
- Web Origins: *
- Roles:
    * extern-user(Users in role: *<user001>*)

Roles:
- app-user
    * Composite Roles enabled
    * Client Roles (Associated Roles:extern-user)
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8080
keycloak.auth-server-url            = http://localhost:3000/
keycloak.realm                      = <realmName>
keycloak.resource                   = <clientName>
keycloak.ssl-required               = external
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
keycloak.bearer-only                = true
keycloak.public-client              = true
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>TRP</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>name</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>18.0.0</keycloak.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Agregado con Springboot Initializr -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Agregado para este proyecto -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**KeycloakSecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.package.realm.config;
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletListenerRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;

import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;

@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class KeycloakSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    // Registra el keycloakAuthenticationProvider con el administrador de autenticación
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider provider = new KeycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

    // Define la estrategia de autenticación
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy(){
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    // Define desde donde se integran las propiedades de Keycloak
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver(KeycloakSpringBootProperties properties) {
        System.out.println("\n" 
        + "\nAuthentication server:" + properties.getAuthServerUrl() 
        + "\nRealm:" + properties.getRealm() 
        + "\nClient: " + properties.getResource()
        + "\n");
        return new MyKeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver(properties);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();  //Con tokens no hay problemas de ataques de Cross Reference 
    }

}
```

**MyKeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver** (class to resolve bean circular reference)

```
package com.package.realm.config;
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment;
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder;
import org.keycloak.adapters.spi.HttpFacade;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    /*
    *  Por defecto, el adaptador Spring Security busca por un archivo de configuración keycloak.json.
        Podemos asegurarnos que busque por la configuración otorgada por el adaptador para Spring boot
        al agregar este bean indicando que aca se encuentran las variables de configuración para acceder
        a KeyCloak
    */

@Configuration
public class MyKeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver extends KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver {
    
    private final KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment;

    public MyKeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver(KeycloakSpringBootProperties properties) {
        keycloakDeployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(HttpFacade.Request facade) {
        return keycloakDeployment;
    }
}
```

**TestController.java**

```
package com.package.realm.controller;

import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @RolesAllowed("extern-user") //This creates problem
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUser() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hola usuario");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getAdmin() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hola administrador");
    }
}
```

Here's an image with every outcome.
[Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py2J8.jpg)

**The error stack**

```
2022-07-07 17:56:42.297 ERROR 4292 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "this.input" is null
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3164) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:66) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.sendRequest(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:98) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.getPublicKey(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:63) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.getPublicKey(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:121) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.createVerifier(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:111) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:47) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:103) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:88) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:67) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:154) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64] 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]  
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]   
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

So, at this point i tried a couple of changes on application.properties, change and test different options on the config file, putting and taking out dependencies, etc. but everything leads to the same 500 error. I don't know what else configure, and the stack doesn't really show something that i can work on.
Did anyone had a similar error? Does anyone have an idea what could i do?

Comment: Which version of Keycloak do you use? Quarkus-based or Wildfly-based distribution?
If wildfly-based, you may be missing a `/auth` at the end of `keycloak.auth-server-url`.

Comment: It's Keycloak 18.0.0 working under Quarkus 2.7.5.Final

Comment: Any feedback about the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, the server url wasn't properly configured. Taking out the /auth in the path helped solving it. The localhost:8000/auth was deprecated since KC 17, and from now on, it's just the server url.

https://www.keycloak.org/migration/migrating-to-quarkus

Answer (score 0):

[Keycloak adapters are deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187) and not quite ready for spring-boot 2.7 and later (still extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for instance).

Get a look at [`spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server). It is ready for latest boot versions and much more portable to other OIDC servers. Tutorial [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) (or [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken) if you prefer to use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` at the price of quite some more Java conf)